# Why is the occuper not conjugated in "Pouvez-vous vous occuper de mon fils ?"

Tags: grammaire, sens, traduction, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Is it because it is after a conjugated verb.

Comment: What's probably confusing you is the fact that there are two *vous*. And the reason you need them is that *s'occuper* is a reflexive verb.

Answer (score 1):

It follows a modal verb (pouvez) and is thus the second verb in a row.

In any sequence of verbs, the second and onward are in the infinitive. (Exception: auxiliaries in temps composes, namely avoir and être, are followed by the past participle.)

A sequence is always broken by a subject (or subject pronoun).

Note that as Peter Shor mentioned, the first *vous* here is the inverted subject of *pouvez*, while the second is the reflexive object of *occuper*.

Some phrases to demonstrate the rules:

> Il ne peut pas être franc avec toi.

> Veux-tu t'asseoir ?

> Elle va acheter des beignets.

> Elle va et elle achète des beignets.

> Nous allons avoir une fête.

> Nous avons eu une fête.

> Nous aurons fêté notre ami.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much of a  choice for "vouloir", which is one of the so-called "verbes  sélectifs".

> (LBU) **§ 299 Verbes sélectifs** 2°  Pouvoir ne se construit ordinairement qu'*avec un infinitif* ou *avec  un pronom neutre* comme objets directs.
>
> - Je ne peux VOUS RÉPONDRE. Il peut TOUT. Il ne peut RIEN. Il LE peut. Il fait
>   ce Qu'il peut.Pouvoir ne se construit ordinairement qu'avec un infinitif ou avec
>   un pronom neutre comme objets directs.

It is different for  other similar  verbs (also "selective): savoir, vouloir, croire, oser, penser, prétendre,  supplier  (de),   tâcher (de)…

There is the construction with an infinitive and other options.

- Il **sait faire** ce travail. - Il **veut faire** ce travail. - Il **croit faire** ce travail. - Il **ose faire** ce travail. - Il **pense faire** ce travail. - Il **prétend faire** ce travail. - Il le supplie **de** faire ce travail.-  Il tâche **de** faire ce travail.
- Il sait  ce travail.- Il sait  **qu**'il travaille. - Il veut  ce travail.  - Il veut  **qu**'il travaille. - Il croit qu'il travaille. - Il **l**'ose. (LBU 3° Pour *oser*, l'Académie. 1935 signale seulement comme compléments soit un infinitif, soit un pronom neutre (le, tout, rien))  - Il pense faire ce travail. - Il pense **qu**'il fait ce travail comme  il   faut. - Il prétend **qu**'il travaille. - Il pense **qu**'il doit travailler.  - Il tâche **que** le travail soit fait.